# How to return Date object in ISO format instead of timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, json, date, spring-boot

Assuming a java class

```
public class User(){
    String name;
    Date dateCreated;
}
```

and a Spring boot controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getUser", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
public User getUser() {
   User newUser = new User();
   newUser.dateCreated = new Date();
   return newUser;
}
```

If I have a rest API endpoint that returns that User object in JSON format, as above, the dateCreated will be send in timestamp format instead of ISO. Is there any way to make Java return the date in Iso format other than having to specify a new return object that has Date as a String?

One way to do this would be to convert Date to a String and send that but I'm wondering if there's a more convenient way..

Comment: What content-type are you serializing to?

Comment: Ah, let me update my post, the response is returned in JSON format.

Comment: what library are you using for JSON serialization/de-serialization? Default for Spring Boot is Jackson.

Comment: ok im gonna level with you here, I have absolutely no clue, I never had to specify a library for JSON serialization/de-serialization this was always done automatically by spring boot so I want to assume that since the default is Jackson, then Jackson it is but I wouldn't be 100% for it. I just have the @RestController on top of my java class and everything is taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update your application.properties with the following:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false
```

Now you can specify the format in your bean as follows:

```
public class User(){
    String name;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date dateCreated;
}
```

Comment: I am having issue here. The date displayed in the json format is 1 day less.